# How to update a progress bar in a form class when the progress occurs in another class

Tags: c#

I've looked all over and I'm struggling to figure out how to properly advance my progress bar. Right now I have it set up inside a `for loop` but it doesn't update till the end because the actual progress happens in a separate class's `for loop` but I don't know how to capture the progress in that class and display it properly within the form's progress bar.

This is the form

```
    private void btn_test_value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When start button is clicked shows message before beginning calculation
        MessageBox.Show("Click OK to begin calculation", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        //Gets a list of values from the GetValue function and stores it in a new list
        var AsmList = myClass.GetValue(txt_value.Text);

        //for each item in that list we add it to the list box in the form
        for (int i = 0; i < AsmList.Count; i++)
        {

            AsmBox.Items.Add(AsmList[i]);

            LoadingText.Text = "Calculating " + (i + 1) + " of " + AsmList.Count;
            LoadBar.ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32((i+1.0)/AsmList.Count * 100);

            LoadBar.ProgressBar.Refresh();


        }

        //Uses the function GetTotalCompat to get the total compatability of the assemblies
        TotalComp.DataSource = myClass.GetTotalCompat(txt_value.Text);

       //Shows the calculation is complete 
        LoadingText.Text = $"Calculation Complete {AsmList.Count} of {AsmList.Count}";
        MessageBox.Show("Done","Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```

This is the separate class. I want the progress bar to progress each time it goes through one of the second for loop's interval.

```
     public List<string> GetValue(string value)
    {
        //Compares each string in the array with all other string values that have not be compared yet
        for (int i = 0; i< asm.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["ASM1"].Value = asm[i];

            for(int p = i+1; p<asm.Length; p++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["ASM2"].Value = asm[p];

                try
                {
                    //Execute the SQL and return a data reader
                    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    if (dr != null && dr.Read())
                    {
                        preResult1 = dr["compatibility"]?.ToString(); 
                        preResult2 = dr["matched"]?.ToString();
                        preResult3 = dr["total"]?.ToString();
                        result = "ASM1:  " + asm[i] + "  ASM2:  " + asm[p] + "  Compatibility:  " + preResult1 + "  Matched:  " + preResult2 + "  Total:  " + preResult3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "ASM1:  " + asm[i] + "  ASM2:  " + asm[p] + "  Compatibility:  0%  No Common Parts";
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.Message;   
                }
                finally
                {
                    //add the result to the list

                    holder.Add(result);  
                }
            }


        }
        // Close the command and release the connection and return the list of values
        CloseCommand(cmd);
        return holder;
    }
```

Someone recommended using events but I'm not sure how I would implement that or if there is a simpler option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. take some time and read [ask]. Try to avoid using pictures of code. It hinders those trying to help you.

Comment: Please post your code as ... you guessed it ... code. Images will only make things worse.

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this. I fixed the question so can this be reopened? Or can I get directed to a similar question with a proper answer

Comment: Can you modify the thing doing the work to implement `IProgress`?  If you can, then the form where the progress bar is will receive events when it is time to update its progress bar, making everything quite easy.

Comment: Also have a look at BackgroundWorker -- it defines the protocol for passing progress updates from worker to manager.

Comment: I've looked at both but being relatively new to this type of coding I didn't quite understand the examples that I saw